# ulem incompatibility with multiple entries in \cite

Tags: citing, incompatibility, ulem

Consider the LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[aps,pre]{revtex4}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\begin{document}

\sout{
asdas~\cite{a1989, b2001}.
}

\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\bibliography{references.bib}

\end{document}
```

where `references.bib` is just a `.bib`-file with some random entries with `a1989` and `b2001` keys.
I compile using

1. Latex
2. BibTex
3. Latex
4. Latex

At step 4, I get the following error

```
! Missing number, treated as zero
```

If I continue, it just ignores and does what it is supposed to.

This only happens when there is more than 1 citation on the same `\cite`. E.g. if I use

```
asdas~\cite{a1989}~cite{b2001}
```

it works fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is covered in the documentation to `ulem` on page 5:

> This loss of local assignments will break some other standard commands, (e.g., `\cite`)
>   which produce multiple ‘words’ using local assignments. The way to protect such commands 
>   is to bury them in an `\mbox`: `\emph{every\-one agrees~\mbox{\cite{you,me}}.}`

In your case using `\mbox` you get

[image: Sample output]

a requested, from:

```
\documentclass[aps,pre]{revtex4}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\begin{document}

\sout{
asdas~\mbox{\cite{a1989,b2001}}.
}

\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\bibliography{references.bib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So, there is no way to solve this other than putting \mbox on all the \cite. Does not sound feasible when ulem is to be used with to track deleted stuff. Nevertheless, your answer is impressive, quite knowledge about ulem!

Comment: [latexdiff](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexdiff) does exactly this, the main downside is that can result in some overfull, but `latexdiff` provides otherways to mark up differences, e.g. via colour.  May be you should investigate that.