# Conflict with cite and changes

Tags: pdftex, changes, cite-package

For a scientific publication, I am writing a modified version of my article which takes in account the comments of my reviewers. I need to identify which modification is due to which reviewer, so I use the `changes` package. Obviously, I have references in my article, so I use the `cite` package.

PDFLaTeX (TexLive 2014) gives me errors when I use the `cite` command within the `deleted` or `replaced` commands of the `changes` package. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{changes}

\begin{document}

As previously observed \deleted{in \cite{someref}, there is no banana here.}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{someref} 
Some ref here.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

I get the following errors:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\UL@stop ...alty \ifnum \lastkern =\thr@@ \egroup
\egroup \ifdim \wd \UL@box...
l.8 ...n \cite{someref}, there is no banana here.}


! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\UL@stop ...num \lastkern =\thr@@ \egroup \egroup
\ifdim \wd \UL@box =\z@ \e...
l.8 ...n \cite{someref}, there is no banana here.}


! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
}
l.8 ...n \cite{someref}, there is no banana here.}


! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
}
l.8 ...n \cite{someref}, there is no banana here.}
```

If I remove the `cite` packages, everything is back to normal. Unfortunately, I need this package.

The question is really close to [this unanswered one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/309125). What should I do?

Comment: Not at pc, but does `\protect\cite` help? Note that the cite package us not required to use `\cite`, that command is already in the core, so you can probably do without it.

Comment: Now I tested it, `\protect` is not enough. But removing the `cite` package is enough. As mentioned, the `cite` package is not required to use the `\cite` command

Comment: I need `cite` for other features not present in the MWE.

Comment: Then you are probably out of luck. Consider writing the author of the package, see the manual

Comment: Hmm, it does seem to work if you use `\noexpand\cite` to keep `\deleted` from expanding too much too early.

Comment: I am surprised that such few people encounter this problem…

Comment: `\noexpand` allow the computation to run, but it does not show the reference number any more in the final document.

Comment: I don't think that many people uses the package. The main issue is that `changes` uses `ulem` to make the strikethrough part. It is well known that this does not always work. Try if `\mbox{\cite{...}}` works.

Comment: The `ulem` manual explicitly mentions `\mbox{\cite{....}}` as a work around.

Comment: The `\mbox` seems to do the trick (in the MWE and in my complete case as well). Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As daleif pointed out in comments, the problem is due to the `ulem` package used to strike deleted changes in the `changes` package. It is known to behave weirdly for some commends, among them `cite`.

As indicated in the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ulem/ulem.pdf), you have to wrap your `cite` in a `mbox` like this:

```
As previously observed \deleted{in \mbox{\cite{someref}}, there is no banana here.}
```

And it works.

A pretty similar problem resolved the same way [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98229/100137).

Answer (score 2):

@Neraste said it right. I just found the same issue and I wanted to avoid the `\mbox{\cite{someref}}` at every reference....
So, based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369689/renewcommand-cite#), I just used:

```
\let\oldcitep\citep
\renewcommand{\citep}[1]{\mbox{\oldcitep{#1}}}
\let\oldcitet\citet
\renewcommand{\citet}[1]{\mbox{\oldcitet{#1}}}
\let\oldcite\cite
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{\mbox{\oldcite{#1}}}
```

It worked perfectly

Answer (score -1):

`\mbox` did not work for me.

However, I have a somewhat satisfactory work around the problem of LaTeX crashing when using `\cite` within `\remove` or `\add` track changes commands. The work around just ignores the reference from being displayed.

Here are the commands I used at the top of the latex document:

```
\usepackage[ignoremode,inline]{trackchanges} % use the "ignoremode" option here

\tcignore{\cite}{1}{0}  % To ignore parenthetical citation (previously used to be \citep)

\tcignore{\citeA}{1}{0} % To ignore in-text citation (previously used to be \citet)
```

It worked for me.