# Conflict with Changes package and cite when using harvard-style bibliography

Tags: citing, harvard-style, changes

I am writing a revised version of an article. I am using the `changes` package to keep track of my revisions.

There is a conflict when using `\added`, `\deleted`, or `\replaced` on a citation. This can be solved by using `\mbox` as suggested in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380033/conflict-with-cite-and-changes). Unfortunately for me it only works for basic citation styles with numbers but not the "authors (year)" style (such as Harvard) required by the journal I am submitting to.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{harvard}


\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
    
@article{ref0,
    title = {title0},
    journal = {journaltitle 0},
    author = {author0},
    month = jan,
    year = {2011},
}   
@article{ref1,
    author = {author1},
    title = {title1},
    journal = {journaltitle 1},
    month = feb,
    year = {2022},
}
@article{ref2,
    author = {author2},
    title = {title2},
    journal = {journaltitle 2},
    month = mar,
    year = {2022},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    
I can cite \cite{ref0} \deleted{but not \mbox{\cite{ref1} \cite{ref2}}}

\bibliographystyle{dcu}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

```
Argument of \XC@col@rlet has an extra }. ...ed{but not \mbox{\cite{ref1} \cite{ref2}}}
Paragraph ended before \XC@col@rlet was complete. ...ed{but not \mbox{\cite{ref1} \cite{ref2}}}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the \cite command robust:

```
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{harvard}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\cite
```

Comment: That worked, thanks!!