# Using \cite in \sout causes errors

Tags: citing, elsarticle, ulem, strikeout

When I use `\cite[something with spaces]{ref}` inside `\sout{...}` I get errors. For the `article` document class it helps to replace spaces by `~`. That doesn't help, however, for the `elsarticle` document class. See minimal working example below:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
% \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}

text
\cite{lamport}
\cite[p.10]{lamport}
\cite[p. 10]{lamport}
\cite[p.~10]{lamport}
\sout{text}
\sout{\cite{lamport}}
\sout{\cite[p.10]{lamport}}
% \sout{\cite[p. 10]{lamport}} % Fails with elsarticle and article
% \sout{\cite[p.~10]{lamport}} % Fails with elsarticle only

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{lamport}
  Leslie Lamport,
  \textit{\LaTeX: a document preparation system},
  Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,
  2nd edition,
  1994.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

For `article` I get

```
! Argument of \UL@word has an extra }.
```

whereas for `elsarticle` I get

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\UL@stop ...z@ \else \UL@putbox \fi \else \egroup 
                                                  \egroup \UL@putbox \fi \if...
```

Is this an error in `ulem`? I would be grateful if anyone knows a quick-fix.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 2):

Although I tried looking for the answer before posting, I only found it afterwards. See [ulem incompatibility with multiple entries in \cite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98222/ulem-incompatibility-with-multiple-entries-in-cite?rq=1). I would prefer that `ulem` just didn't have this problem, but a quick-fix seems to be putting `\cite` in an `\mbox`:

```
\sout{\mbox{\cite[p. 10]{lamport}}} % Fails with elsarticle and article
\sout{\mbox{\cite[p.~10]{lamport}}} % Fails with elsarticle only
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply put curly brackets around `p. 10`:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
% \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}


\sout{\cite[{p. 10}]{lamport}}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{lamport}
  Leslie Lamport,
  \textit{\LaTeX: a document preparation system},
  Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,
  2nd edition,
  1994.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! Though I actually wanted the non-break space there, and `{p.~10}` still gives error on `elsarticle`.