# How do I top strikethrough (\sout) interfering with bold font (\textbf) in Chinese?

Tags: bold, ulem, chinese

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\begin{document}

\textbf{a a a} a a a，\textbf{aaa}aaa.

\sout{\textbf{a a a} a a a，\textbf{aaa}aaa.}

\textbf{我我我}我我我，\textbf{我我我}我我我。

\sout{\textbf{我我我}我我我，\textbf{我我我}我我我。} 

\end{document}
```

Output, compiled using XeLaTeX:

> [image: When using \sout, instead of showing 我我我 in bold, it only shows 我 in bold.]

The last line is not my expected output, which is:

> <s>**我我我**我我我，**我我我**我我我。</s>

It looks like the `\sout` command is interfering with bold font in Chinese (but not in English).  I'm not sure how to fix this.  I tried putting `\protect` before the `\textbf`, but nothing changed.  Even if I change it to

```
\sout{{\bf 我我我}我我我，\textbf{我}\textbf{我}\textbf{我}我我我。}
```

nothing changes.  Weird.

**Question**: How do I top strikethrough (\sout) interfering with bold font (\textbf) in Chinese?

I found a workaround via:

```
\sout{\textbf{我}}\sout{\textbf{我}}\sout{\textbf{我}}我我我，\sout{\textbf{我}}\sout{\textbf{我}}\sout{\textbf{我}}我我我。
```

It's somewhat ridiculous, but it works.

Comment: which engine is this? (pdflatex?)

Comment: It's xelatex; better for Chinese.

Comment: I guess it's probably some bug with ulem package (how it allow linebreak within striked segment)... may have to read source code to fix.

Comment: Reading the documentation... it suggests that adding a group is sufficient, but it's not (e.g. `\sout{\textbf{我我我}我我我，{\textbf{我我我}}我我我。}`).  Forcing a box `\sout{\textbf{我我我}我我我，\mbox{\textbf{我我我}}我我我。}` does work however.

Comment: Somewhat similar to [citing - Using \cite in \sout causes errors - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/487328/using-cite-in-sout-causes-errors). The "bury in mbox" trick is mentioned in the documentation

Comment: An empty \mbox{} before the \textbf works. But basically the processing code of xeCJK for the full-width comma and other punctuation and the processing code of ulem clash here. If you mix both you should always expects side effects.